# Understanding Neo4j Algo write back option

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-algorithm

I've been looking into Neo4j graph algorithms and I've seen that a number of algorithms are only available in the write back format while others have both stream and write back implementations. However, I haven't been able to find anything explaining the difference between the two.

So my questions are:

- When and Why is write back a better implementation than stream? (basically what are the advantages and disadvantages of write back)
- How does write back handle graph alterations? (if we add/remove nodes or edges from the graph after running the algorithm is there any way to tell that the property is now invalid?)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see all graph algos have the stream & write behaviour, except some that only have the stream one (pretty much all the path algos).

Graph algos consume a lot of resources (they work on the entire graph), so if you have a big dataset, it will take times.

That's why it's really usefull to write back the result, it allows you to make some cypher queries based on the result of your graph algos.

For your question about the invalidation, there is no internal mecanism to do it, but with APOC, you can  create a trigger to invalidate the result when a node is created/deleted or when you add/remove a relationship.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  For the first part, [minimum weight spanning tree](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/) is one that only has write back.